# javascriptからphpへの引数について

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

お世話になります。
javascriptからphpへのデータ渡しについて質問です。
下記のように記述したのですが引数がうまく渡っていません。
どこがおかしいのでしょうか？
phpは正常に起動できているようです。
ajaxは経験がほとんどないのでアドバイスいただければ幸いです.
ソースコードは下記です。

html

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'sample.php',
    data: {
      'test': 'こんにちは'
    },
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
```

php

```
echo $_POST["test"];
```

Comment: どのような結果をもって引数がうまく渡っていないと判断したのか具体的に書いてください。あと、ソースコードは抜粋ではなくできるだけ完全なものを載せてください。

Comment: とりあえず、うまく動いていないならマルチバイト文字を送るのをやめてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

皆様
色々回答ありがとうございました。
ソースがまとまっていなくて全ソース出せなかったのですが、
ajaxの記述がheadの外にあり、位置を変えたところ無事に動きました。
phpが動いていたと判断したのはphpでログを出していたので為です。

お騒がせして申し訳ございません。

Answer (score 0):

phpファイルに間違いましたね。

サーバに送信する値(data)はオブジェクトだから、phpファイルにechoを使わずに、print_rを使うとうまくいけると思います。つまり、下記の通り

print_r($_POST);

Comment: 質問に書かれているのは `$_POST["test"]` ですから、`$_POST` 全体を出力しようとしているわけではありません。また、 `$_POST` は確かに連想配列ですが、これは `$.ajax()` にオブジェクトを渡していることとは無関係です。